# I don't want to keep the column that was used to create a data.table subset. How can I accomplish this?

Tags: r, data.table

If this is my data table:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=2), y=c(1,3), v=1:6)
setkey(DT, y)

DT
#    x y v
# 1: a 1 1
# 2: b 1 3
# 3: c 1 5
# 4: a 3 2
# 5: b 3 4
# 6: c 3 6
```

and I now create subsets from this data table; variable y gets included in the result. Is there a way to drop it?

```
DT1 <- DT[ , .SD[ , paste(x, v, sep="", collapse="_")], by=y]
DT1
#    y       V1
# 1: 1 a1_b3_c5
# 2: 3 a2_b4_c6
```

I realize I can do so by the following additional step:

```
DT1 <- DT1[,y:=NULL]
```

.. but wondering if there is an option to drop y while creating subsets?

Comment: There is a request for this (not having the "by" columns returned) https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2061 Fyi, you do not need to do DT1 <- DT1[, y :=NULL], it is sufficient to do DT1[, y:=NULL] since this makes the modification in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `split`

```
DT[, .(V1 = unlist(lapply(split(.SD[, .(x, v)], y), 
        function(x) do.call(paste, c(x, sep="", collapse="_")))))]
#         V1
#1: a1_b3_c5
#2: a2_b4_c6
```

---

Or there is no need to create new object as the assignment (`:=`) step can be chained before creating another object

```
DT[ , paste(x, v, sep="", collapse="_"), by=y][, y := NULL][]
#.       V1
#1: a1_b3_c5
#2: a2_b4_c6
```

Answer (score 4):

Using split.data.table and magrittr:

```
library(magrittr)
split(DT, by="y", keep.by=FALSE) %>% 
  sapply(. %$% paste(x, v, sep="", collapse="_"))

#          1          3 
# "a1_b3_c5" "a2_b4_c6"
```

`unname` could be added after `sapply` if the names (1 & 3 above) are not wanted.

For comparison with @akrun's answer, see `?split.data.table`, which explains the use of `by=` instead of `f=`. If the `keep.by=` argument were [available in `DT[...]`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2061), the OP's problem could be solved more directly.

Comment: I think the `keep.by` argument would be useful in `by`